# I get this SQL A transport-level error, but not all the time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I try to query data from the database and sometimes I get this error in my log:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
> server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The handle is invalid.)
> The code is inside a try-catch block.

What is weird is that I do not get this error all the time. The catch block does get executed.

However, whether I get the error or not, the Drop Down Lists I am trying to populate do not get populated. It seems like there is no data being returned from the query.

I am making a connection to the database, the data is in there, I can open a connection and run queries to the database. The database is on the same machine as where I'm running the code from.

Also, the code works when I connect to the database on the server, but I am trying to make a local database to work when I don't have connection to the server. I just have to make a change to the connection string when I want to run from the local database.

Here is the function that queries the database:

```
public static void QueryDB(string query)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Connection = MyConn;
        if (dr != null) dr.Dispose();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

Here is the connection string to connect to the database:

```
MyConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=tcp:localhost; Database=EscalationManagementSystem; Integrated Security=true;");
```

Is there a setting that is wrong or could this be a bug in the code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you have not given us any code to review making assumptions about what is causing this problem is not reliablely feasible.

Comment: I'm guessing `dr` is some sore of `SqlDataReader`?  Is that a global var?

Comment: Sorry, yes `dr` is a `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: Try to install all updates to MS Windows and MS SQL Server

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a bug in your code.  I don't think you should have a single `SqlDataReader` and `SqlCommand` that is shared by all calls to the database.

Instead, you should instantiate a new `SqlDataReader` and `SqlCommand` for each call to the database, and dispose (and close) them when the application is finished with that specific SQL call.

My guess as to what is happening in your situation would be that the `SqlDataReader` or `SqlCommand` is being pulled out from under you by another call to the database, and that the issue is intermittent because it's a race condition.

Comment: Do you suggest to put the `SqlDataReader` and `SqlCommand` inside a `using` block?

Comment: I put all `SqlDataReader` and `SqlCommand` in `using` blocks but it still did not work. Also, `SqlDataReader` and/or `SqlCommand` being pulled out from under me doesn't make sense because the database is local and will only be accessed when the application is run locally. Everything works when i use the served database.

Answer (score 3):

Such an error usually appears when your connection to the instance of the Sql server is reset.

The cause maybe due to reset of the network connection.

Other cause might be:

You request the SQL Server and receive the data from the Connection pool. Now something bad happens to the SQL Server (service restart) and you make a postback to get data.

**Check to make sure that your connection does not break between subsequent requests.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: I checked the connection throughout the entire execution and its state was always open. I still was not seeing the data show up.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to the fact that you have not released your database connection. Just add a `Finally` statement in your code and add `conn.Close()` and `conn.Dispose()`. I am sure it will work fine.

```
finally 
{
    cmd.Connection.Close();
    cmd.Connection.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the query I was executing was reading data from an Excel file using ACE OLE DB drive (Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0). The driver had got corrupted and reinstalling the same fixed the issue.

The script was being executed from PowerShell and it was crashing SQL Server instance also and after that the SQL Server instance will not restart. It was hard to find this cause.

The error message received was:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : A transport-level error has occurred when receiving
> results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 -
> The pipe has been ended.)  Msg 109, Level 20, State 0, Procedure ,
> Line 0.

I was going all around changing login, checking folder permissions, error log, database corruption etc. but in my case this was the cause. May help someone.